# Get changed item from CollectionChanged event using TrulyObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, class, events, observablecollection

I'm using a `TrulyObservableCollection` as a datasource in a WPF DataGrid.  My class implements the `PropertyChange` event properly (I get notification when a property changes).  The `CollectionChanged` event gets triggered as well.  However, my issue lies in the connection between the `PropertyChanged` event and `CollectionChanged` event.  I can see in the `PropertyChanged` event which item is being changed (in this case the `sender` object), however I can't seem to find a way to see which one is changed from within the `CollectionChanged` event.  The `sender` object is the whole collection.  What's the best way to see which item has changed in the `CollectionChanged` event?  The relevant code snippets are below.  Thank you for your help, and let me know if there needs to be some clarification.

Code for setting up the collection:

```
    private void populateBret()
    {
        bretList = new TrulyObservableCollection<BestServiceLibrary.bretItem>(BestClass.BestService.getBretList().ToList());
        bretList.CollectionChanged += bretList_CollectionChanged;
        dgBretList.ItemsSource = bretList;
        dgBretList.Items.Refresh();
    }

    void bretList_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do stuff here with the specific item that has changed
    }
```

Class that is used in the collection:

```
public class bretItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int _blID;
    public string _blGroup;

    [DataMember]
    public int blID
    {
        get { return _blID; }
        set
        {
            _blID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("blID");
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string blGroup
    {
        get { return _blGroup; }
        set
        {
            _blGroup = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("blGroup");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged (String name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

TrulyObservableCollection class

```
public class TrulyObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public TrulyObservableCollection()
            : base()
        {
            CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(TrulyObservableCollection_CollectionChanged);
        }
        public TrulyObservableCollection(List<T> list)
            : base(list)
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                item.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
            CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(TrulyObservableCollection_CollectionChanged);
        }

        void TrulyObservableCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                foreach (Object item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
                }
            }
            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach (Object item in e.OldItems)
                {
                    (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
                }
            }
        }

        void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs a = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
            OnCollectionChanged(a);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

In the `item_PropertyChanged` event the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` are set with `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset`.  This causes the `OldItems` and `NewItems` to be null, therefore I can't get the changed item in that case.  I can't use `.Add` as the Datagrid is updated with an additional item.  I can't appear to get `.Replace` to work either to get the changed item.

Comment: Can you explain more about why are concerned with changes to properties of objects within the collection and why that is important to handled within the collection?

Comment: Why not use a separate class to track the item that is changing?

Comment: @JoshC., I'm using this to know when to process saving changes and whatnot to our database (various reasons why the datagrid can't have a direct binding to the database that I will not get into). If I were to use a separate class to track, how would I go about setting that up?  Are you suggesting that I have a class that has a list of the `bretItem` instead of using an `ObservableCollection`? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

In your `ViewModel` that contains the `ObservableCollection` of `bretItem`, the ViewModel subscribes to the `CollectionChanged` event of the `ObservableCollection`.

This will prevent the need of a new class `TrulyObservableCollection` derived from `ObservableCollection` that is coupled to the items within its collection.

Within the handler in your `ViewModel`, you can add and remove the `PropertyChanged` event handler as you are now. Since it is now your `ViewModel` that is being informed of the changes to objects within the collection, you can take the appropriate action.

```
public class BretListViewModel
{

    private void populateBret()
    {
        bretList = new ObservableCollection<BestServiceLibrary.bretItem>(BestClass.BestService.getBretList().ToList());
        bretList.CollectionChanged += bretList_CollectionChanged;              
    }

    void bretList_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Object item in e.NewItems)
            {
                (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }
        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Object item in e.OldItems)
            {
                (item as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(item_PropertyChanged);
            }
        }
    }


    void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bret = sender as bretItem;

        //Update the database now!

        //One note:
        //The ObservableCollection raises its change event as each item changes.
        //You should consider a method of batching the changes (probably using an ICommand)
    }

}
```

**A Thing of Note:**

As an aside, it looks like you are breaking the `MVVM` pattern based upon this snippet:

```
dgBretList.ItemsSource = bretList;
dgBretList.Items.Refresh();
```

You probably should consider loading your `ViewModel` and binding your `View` to it instead of coding logic in the code-behind of your `View`.

Comment: Hadn't really thought about a `ViewModel`.  Your sample looks perfect.  Since I'll have a few different classes with the same idea, I was trying to stick with a generalized "ViewModel" instead of a specific one.  This, however, isn't as bad as I thought it would be.  Looks like it should work like a gem though, thank you!  In response to your note, the bretList is populated through a WCF operation and as far as I'm aware there isn't a way to bind this directly through the xaml.

Comment: @jmgardn2 I didn't mean bind through xaml, I meant build your collection, pass it into the ViewModel (think DI), then bind your xaml to the ViewModel. You don't want to code your View to your data sources.

Comment: I think I'm understanding this better now.  Thank you again for your help and explanations.  I will test out the code shortly.

Answer (score 2):

It's not appropriate to use the collection changed event in this way because it's only meant to be fired when adding/removing items from the collection. Which is why you've hit a wall. You're also in danger of breaking the Liskov substitution principle with this approach.

It's probably better to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your collection class and fire that event when one of your items fires its property changed event.

Comment: I'm looking to handle when an item is changed.  Currently, the `PropertyChanged` event fires the `CollectionChanged` event.  I was hoping to be able to handle a changed property in the `CollectionChanged` event.

Comment: Clarifying questions should be posted as comments, not answers.

Comment: @Servy: Question: "Get changed item from CollectionChanged" Answer: Look at the OldItems and NewItems collections. If clarifying questions in answers is wrong then half of stackoverflow is also wrong.

Comment: @PhilGan Half of all answers are not clarifying questions.  There are a fair number of them, but the community is pretty good about ensuring they get deleted or converted to comments.

Comment: @PhilGan, thank you for the updated info.  Based on this, I should have my function calls for handling the updated item in the `item_PropertyChanged` event itself correct?